# How to forbid folder deletion in SP Online document library?

Tags: folder, lock

I thought this information would be easy to find on google or on this site but can't find it. Sorry in advance if I missed it.

I have a document library accessible by 100+ people and we decide to lock the possibility to delete any folder because of the risks a non-IT skilled person accidentally remove all our files.
My idea was to go in the SP permissions level and uncheck something lie 'Delete folder' but it doesn't exist like that.
I have reviewed the list several time and can't find to which permission level this right to delete folder is associated to. Below the list of permissions I can modify. Can somebody clarify to me how I can set-up a permission level were people can manage files (create, edit, delete) but can't delete any folder?

Many thanks in advance

PS: the list of permission level:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have already unchecked **'Manage Lists'** permission. It should restrict the deletion of the whole list. Out of the box **'Contribute'** permission should work in your case, as it excludes 'Manage List', which is part of out of the box **'Edit'** permission.

```
Edit – Can add, edit and delete lists; can view, add, update and delete list items and documents
Contribute – Can view, add, update, and delete list items and documents
```

Please let me know if this is not working.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. The team still have the rights to delete a folder. So I assume they are only forbidden to delete the hole library. Is there any way to lock the deletion of the sub-folders?